# Metaproving Question.

Tags: logic

Prove that $ \vdash ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A $

I want to make sure my answer is right as the textbook has no solutions.

I am using Equational Proof. The textbook is "Mathematical Logic" For Tourlakis.

My answer :

$$ ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ <axiom + leib; c-part:(p\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A; p \ fresh>$$
$$ ((A \lor B \equiv B)\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom + leib; c-part: p \rightarrow A; p\ fresh>$$
$$(A \lor B \equiv B \lor A \equiv A) \rightarrow A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom + leib: c-part : A \lor B \equiv B \lor p\ ; p\ fresh>$$
$$(A \lor B \equiv B \lor T) \rightarrow A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom + leib: c-part : A \lor p \lor T:\ p\ fresh>$$
$$(A \lor T \lor T)\rightarrow A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom + leib ; c-part: (A \lor p) \rightarrow A; p\ fresh>$$
$$(A \lor T) \rightarrow A$$
$$\Rightarrow<axiom>$$
$$A \lor T \lor A \equiv A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom + leib; c-part: p \lor T \equiv A ; p\ fresh>$$
$$A \lor T \equiv A$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom>$$
$$A \lor A \equiv T$$
$$\Rightarrow <axiom>$$
$$A \equiv T$$
$$\Rightarrow<axiom>$$
$$A$$

Axioms and theorems :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm really finding your post to be confusing to follow, as it now appears.

Comment: Why is it confusing to follow? I just want to see if my answer is right or wrong.

Comment: E.g., $\Rightarrow <axiom + leib: c-part : A \lor p \lor T:\ p\ fresh>$. It would help if you explained some terms you're using, if you'd not write $text$ but rather $\text{text}$: `\text{text}` or *text*: `*text*`

Comment: @amWhy - I says that the starting point is **Implication** axiom [Tourlakis, page 43] : $A \rightarrow B \equiv A \lor B \equiv B$ and used *Leibniz* rule [Tourlakis, page 40] in order to obtain... But I'm not sure of the "procedure" : why he starts from the conclusion ? In order to prove *Peirce's law*, we must start **from** an axiom and (through application of the rules) construct a "chain of equivalences" ending with the formula to be proved...

Comment: That's what I gathered. Thanks @Mauro. I agree with your "puzzlement:" "why he starts from the conclusion..."

Comment: There is a template to use to prove this, which is start with what you want to prove and end with an axiom or previously proved theorem. That's what i did.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA See my edit please. I put the axioms i used in the proof.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. That would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove that

> $ \vdash ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A $

in *Equational Logic* [all references to the textbook of George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008)].

I think that we must use **2.6.1 Metatheorem. (Deduction Theorem)** :

> If $\Gamma \cup \{ C \} \vdash D$, then also $\Gamma \vdash C \rightarrow D$.

This theorem allows us to "reduce the complexity" of the formula to be proved, starting from the "assumption" $C$ and deriving $D$.

In our case :

> $\Gamma = \emptyset $ , $\quad C$ will be $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \quad $ and $\quad D$ will be $A$.

I will use the *Equational Proof Layout* [page 65], as done by the OP, i.e. a chain of equivalences with annotations : $A_1 \Leftrightarrow$  (annotation) ... $\Leftrightarrow$ (annotation) $A_n$

Having said that, we will start with :

$$ (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib; "C-part" is} \ p \rightarrow A \ >$$

*Note*. We have used axiom (11) : **Implication** [page 43] : $A \rightarrow B \equiv A \lor B \equiv B$, and we have used Equanimity and Leibniz merged, that is the "derived rule" [see Tourlakis, page 57, **2.1.16 Theorem (Eqn + Leib Merged)**] :  $C[p := A], A \equiv B \vdash  C[p := B]$; we will call it "Leib".

$$ (A \lor B \equiv B)\rightarrow A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib; "C-part" is} \ (A \lor B) \equiv B \equiv p \ >$$

*Note*. We have used as axiom : **Th.2.4.11** [page 70] : $\vdash C \rightarrow A \equiv \lnot C \lor A$.
$$\lnot [(A \lor B) \equiv B ]\lor A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib; "C-part" is} \ p \lor A \ >$$

*Note*. We have used axiom (4) : **Introduction of** $\lnot$ : $\lnot A \equiv A \equiv \bot$.
$$((A \lor B )\equiv B) \equiv \bot) \lor A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib, with axiom (8) : Distributivity of}  \lor \text{over} \equiv \ >$$
$$[(A \lor B) \equiv B] \lor A \equiv A \lor \bot$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib, where axiom is Th.2.4.10} \vdash A \lor \bot \equiv A \ >$$
$$[(A \lor B) \equiv B] \lor A \equiv A $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Leib, with axiom (8) : Distributivity of} \lor \text{over} \equiv \ >$$
$$(A \lor B) \lor A \equiv (A \lor B) \equiv A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{by axioms (5) and (6) : Associativity and Symmetry of} \lor \ >$$
$$(A \lor A) \lor B \equiv A \lor B \equiv A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{by axiom (7) : Idempotency of} \lor \ >$$
$$A \lor B \equiv A \lor B \equiv A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ < \text{axiom + Equanimity, where axiom is Th.2.1.12} \vdash A \equiv A \ >$$
$$A$$

Finally having derived $A$ from the "assumption" $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A$, i.e.

> $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \vdash A$

we may invoke the *Deduction Theorem* [**2.6.1 Metatheorem**] and conclude :

> $\vdash ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$.
>
> > Please, check !

Comment: How did you use Equanimity in the last step ? I think we never used it in Equational Style Proof.

Comment: @Tennisman - of course we use the "axiom" $A \equiv A$ in the form : $A \lor B \equiv A \lor B$. Equanimity [pag.40] allows us to "detach" (like modus ponens) $B$ form the two premises $A$ and $A \equiv B$. In our case, $A$ is $A \lor B \equiv A \lor B$ and $A \equiv B$ is $A \lor B \equiv A \lor B \equiv A$.

Comment: I got it thank you. I have another question. The question was prove that $ \vDash_{taut} B \equiv (p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot p \lor q \lor r) $. The solution for that question was a truth table for that formula and in the table the formula evaluates to false two times. So how this could be a tautology ? ( The answer says it's tautology). Actually the question ask to prove $ \vdash B \equiv (p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot p \lor q \lor r) $ ( he used post's theorem)

Comment: The question says: Let B be a formula in which the variables p,q,r occur, but no others, and whose truth table has a result f only in the rows f,t,f(state for p,q,r in that order) and t,f,f. Show that B is provably equivalent to the formula $ p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot p \lor q \lor r) $. The question in tourlakis book in chapter 3 . Question 3.(a)